# What are large, 'artificial' atoms for? When making 'quantum' devices?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement

Several recent things I have read say that 'quantum' materials taking advantage of entanglement, among other quantum properties, work better if very large, synthetic/artificial 'atoms' are used, which have a diameter the same size as the wavelength of the microwaves used to control them...

Why do 'artificial' atoms need to be the same diameter as the wavelength of the EM radiation used to manipulate them?

Comment: There is a [Quantum Computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/). If you check the site and don't see this answered there, you could flag for a moderator and inquire about possibly having this post migrated to that site. I see that you've joined the site but admirably have refrained from cross-posting there, kudos!